# mysql insert syntax for blob data through Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert, blob

I want to insert an img file in mysql database, can anyone provide normal insert statement for inserting blob into mysql database. How i can do it as if i specify the path it stores the path only not the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`LOAD_FILE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function.